# Efficient view of records with the most current revision stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, call it `P`, that currently has a series of records, each with a unique key:

```
Key1 value1
Key2 value2
Key3 value3
```

and so on, where each value is actually a set of columns.

I now have a requirement to make these records mutable, and to record the history of changes as an audit log.

I am thinking the best way to do this is to modify `P` so that it is

```
Key1 Rev1 value1
Key1 Rev2 value1a
Key2 Rev1 value2
Key2 Rev2 value2a
```

and so on.   The most current record for any given key would always have the highest revision marker.

The problem is, this ruins comparability for queries that expect only current records.   I am thinking of renaming `P` to something like `PComplete` and creating a view `P` that would only select the highest revision marker for each key, and omit the revision marker, thus emulating the original table `P`.

As I am not primarily a SQL expert:

Is this a solid technique?
What is the best way to design the new view `P` so that it selects the most current (call it greatest) row for each present key in the base view `PBase`?

Site pointers are most welcome; I have no idea what terms to Google to find best practice methods for this type of solution.

Note:  this is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Part one of your question is easy: Using a revision column like that is pretty much industry standard, at least where I work.

As for viewing the most up-to-date records, there is no syntactically-beautiful way to do this, unfortunately (which is strange, because this comes up all the time, see [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)!). But if you've got an underlying records table:

```
CREATE TABLE Records (
RecordID int,
RevisionID int,
ValueA varchar(50),
...
)
```

One way of showing only the latest revisions (and the way I personally do it) is, like you said, through a view:

```
CREATE VIEW CurrentRecords AS
SELECT r.RecordID,
   r.ValueA
   ...
FROM Records AS r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT RecordID, MAX(RevisionID) AS RevisionID
    FROM Records
    GROUP BY RecordID
) AS maxRev on maxRev.RecordID = r.RecordID AND maxRev.RevisionID = r.RevisionID
```

Where you first perform a lookup on the revision ID for the latest revision by record ID, and then use that link to actually get the record. As long as there is an index on the RevisionID column, you shouldn't have performance problems (it will be a fast index lookup, as opposed to a table scan, to determine the max revision ID).

Googling "sql select row with max value" brings up a bunch of S-O links, and this one generally agrees with what I've written here: [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column). Feel free to browse the tagged section, S-O post, and google query I have provided if you want to learn more!

Comment: I already have a column in the table `rowversion` of type `timestamp` which I have read is actually a `rowversion` data type alias.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx   Do you know if this is strictly increasing, so that I could use it directly as the revision marker?  Its a sad story, I *wanted* a true timestamp, but that isn't what I have--but maybe it will be good for this purpose :-)

Comment: The rowversion datatype is meant to mark when a row is updated, and only guarantees that a row is different than it used to be. It *might* work, but you should probably set up a trigger that checks the current latest revision ID and increments that, because if two records are inserted simultaneously, then a timestamp could end up being ambiguous (again, SQL designers making it harder than it should be!)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with approach like this:

- create another table that will be named PHistory and that will have exactly the same columns as original one plus one more column for revision number (int) or updated date (datetime), you can also add ID column as primary key
- use update triggers on the main table to copy all values from P table into PHistorty table every time there is an update in the main table

This will make things clean when you create queries. You always select from P table when you want the latest version and from PHistorty when you want to see some revision.